# Why can't I connect to this service when launched via Upstart?

Tags: upstart, services

I have a web service written in Golang that I need to fire up using Upstart.

I can run the service executable (named word) on port 5555 from within it's directory manually like so:

```
PORT=5555 ./word
```

Then `curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/word` returns the correct response (which is some JSON).

Now, I need to run this service via Upstart. I've written this script (called word.conf):

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

chdir /home/word

setgid word
setuid word

export PORT=5555
exec ./word
```

I run it via `sudo start word`

`status word` then tells me that the service is running and I see no errors in the Upstart error logs.

When trying to hit the service again via `curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/word` I get a `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host` error.

This seems like it has to be some sort of permissions issue, but I can't pinpoint it.

I tried removing the `setgid` and `setuid` and running with no luck. I do have a user called `word`.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your complete script, then it has a two simple problems. `exec` should be in a `script [...] end script` like this:

```
script
    exec ./word
end script
```

and the export variable should be declared first with a `env` stanza:

```
env PORT=5555
export PORT
```

So the whole script should looks like:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

chdir /home/word

setgid word
setuid word

env PORT=5555
export PORT

script
    exec ./word
end script
```

I would also instead of calling `./word` would call the interpreter first. If it's a bash script:

```
exec /usr/bin/env bash ./word
```

python:

```
exec /usr/bin/env python word
```

References:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#env
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#export
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#script

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I made all the updates you suggested, but I'm still running into the same "couldn't connect to host" error unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be working now. I may have just needed to run `initctl reload word` after I made the edits you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your environment variable using env, and specify the interpreter to call your script:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

chdir /home/word

setgid word
setuid word

env PORT=5555
export PORT

exec go run word
```

You may not need to 'export PORT' if this is the only process that uses it, and if the interpreter is defined in the script then you may not even need to include it in the exec.